# Get slice of Python list based on indices: list of list of dicts

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a structure as below:

```
[[{'w': [0.5372377247650572, 1.9111341091016385, -3.2165806256024116, -1.7154987465370053, 1.0917999534858416], 'o': 0.0004326739879156587, 'd': 3.586499431857422e-05}],[{'w': [7.298542669399767, -3.9021024252822105], 'o': 0.019860841402923542, 'd': 0.00105997759946847}, {'w': [-2.8024625186056764, -0.34819658506990847], 'o': 0.4135257109795849, 'd': -0.0016469874583619935}, {'w': [-6.018257518762189, 0.3317488378886934], 'o': 0.5815513019444986, 'd': -1.1787471334339458e-05}]]
```

It is a list of lists of dicts, and these dicts contain keys 'w', 'o', 'd'. I want to create a slice of this structure such that I'm left with only the 'd' values:

```
3.586499431857422e-05, 0.00105997759946847, -0.0016469874583619935, -1.1787471334339458e-05
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
structure = [[{'w': [0.5372377247650572, 1.9111341091016385, -3.2165806256024116, -1.7154987465370053, 1.0917999534858416], 'o': 0.0004326739879156587, 'd': 3.586499431857422e-05}],[{'w': [7.298542669399767, -3.9021024252822105], 'o': 0.019860841402923542, 'd': 0.00105997759946847}, {'w': [-2.8024625186056764, -0.34819658506990847], 'o': 0.4135257109795849, 'd': -0.0016469874583619935}, {'w': [-6.018257518762189, 0.3317488378886934], 'o': 0.5815513019444986, 'd': -1.1787471334339458e-05}]]
d_values = [ x['d'] for row in structure for x in row ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Without list comprehension:

```
    res=[]
    for list_dicts in original_matrix:
        for current_dict in list_dicts:
            res.append(current_dict['d'])
    print(res)
```